# How to store the payload in separate columns using the Semantic Logging Application Block's SqlDatabaseSink

Tags: enterprise-library-6, semantic-logging, slab

How can the SqlDatabaseSink store the payload in separate columns?  It's mentioned in the documentation, but I haven't seen it done anywhere.  When I've tried, the payload is always stored as a JSON string.  Any ideas?

Source: [Developing event sources using the .NET EventSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774985(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Under "Specifying the event and its payload" it states:

> Some sinks will store payload items individually; for example, the SQL
>   Database sink and the Azure Table Storage sink in the Semantic Logging
>   Application Block store each payload item in a separate column.

Is the documentation wrong regarding the SqlDatabaseSink?  I've heard DEVs claim that the Azure Sink works.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the documentation is incorrect after all.  It only works with the Azure Sink as explained [here](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/571952) by an Enterprise Library Support Engineer.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the source so the payload is stored in an XML column in Sql Server, that makes for easy querying. See this fork: https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/semantic-logging